# Writing to a TextView outside of a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using a TextView inside of a Fragment.

I wish to update this TextView outside of the fragment (but also outside of an activity) from a callback class.

For example the user scrolls, the callback is called somewhere in my package, and I want the fragment view to be updated.

Can anybody explain how to do this? I did use a Local Broadcast Receiver but it wasn't fast enough in its updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Otto`: http://square.github.io/otto/

```
public class UpdateEvent {
    private String string;

    public UpdateListEvent(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }
}

...
    ...
    public void update() {
       SingletonBus.INSTANCE.getBus().post(new UpdateListEvent(editText.getText().toString()));
    }
...

public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SingletonBus.INSTANCE.getBus().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        SingletonBus.INSTANCE.getBus().unregister(this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onUpdateEvent(UpdateEvent e) {
        //do something
    }
}


public enum SingletonBus {
    INSTANCE;

    private Bus bus;

    private SingletonBus() {
        this.bus = new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.ANY);
    }

    public Bus getBus() {
        return bus;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eventually looked at Otto but as we had Guava I implemented a singleton eventbus and used Guava publish/subscribe model to pass stuff around.

Otto however looks very similar.

Answer (score 0):

[EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) is a nice and elegant way for communication between modules in Android apps. In this way you should register your fragment as a event subscriber, and post a this specific event from other part of your code. Keep in mind that only UI thread can work with Views.

Answer (score 0):

I don't  exactly understand what you want to achieve and why BroadcastReceiver does not work for you, but you may either:

1) try using callbacks (if it is possible in your app design);

2) try using  [this](https://github.com/square/otto) or [that](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) event bus implementation;

Both would work pretty fast without much overhead, compared to broadcasting. 
In case 2 you won't have to maintain callback dependencies/references.

Comment: Actually you are correct, the (Local) Broadcast Receiver did work, it was my code logic that was flawed leading me to believe that the Receiver was slow... although by that time I had implemented a Guava solution that had other benefits. Thanks.